# Angular how to test a nested component with nested ng-template?

Tags: angular, nested, components, ng-template

I wanted to make reusable and extensible components in Angular, so I followed this article: https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/reusable-components-with-configurable-templates-in-angular-3c55741c97f3.

It works fine, but I get in to trouble when it comes to writing tests. I can't access any DOM element from inside the `ng-template` with `querySelector(...)` - I get `null`.

```
<app-edit [dialogTitle]="'Edit'">

    <ng-template editTopLayout>
        <div fxLayout="row">
            <div fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end center">
                <button id="btn-release" (click)="onRelease()" mat-stroked-button color="primary" [disabled]="buttonsDisabled">Release</button>
                <button id="btn-reject" (click)="onReject()" mat-stroked-button color="warn" [disabled]="buttonsDisabled">Reject</button>
                <button id="btn-cancel" (click)="onCancel()" mat-stroked-button [disabled]="buttonsDisabled">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="2"></div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

</app-edit>
```

In the above sample, the tested component extends the `app-edit` component with custom content via the `EditTopLayoutDirective`.

My aim was to test, whether a correct action is performed after clicking a certain button from the `ng-template` but as I said, when using `fixture.querySelector(...)` in the test, I get `null`.

**Ho can I access the buttons inside `ng-template` to click them pragmatically?**

Edit: Here is the test file

```
describe('MyTestedComponent', () => {
  let component: MyTestedComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyTestedComponent>;
  let fb = new FormBuilder();

  let configService: ConfigurationService;
  let eventEmitterSpy;
  let paymentServiceStub = {
    rejectPayments: jasmine.createSpy('rejectPayments'),
    releasePayments: jasmine.createSpy('releasePayments')
  };
  let dialogServiceStub = { confirmContinuation: jasmine.createSpy('confirmContinuation') };
  let configSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        DemoMaterialModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        MyTestedComponent,
        EditComponent,
        MoneyComponent,
        EditTopLayoutDirective
      ],
      providers: [
        TemplateService,
        AccountService,
        AlertService,
        ConfigurationService,
        {
          provide: DialogService,
          useValue: dialogServiceStub
        },
        {
          provide: PaymentService,
          useValue: paymentServiceStub
        },
        {
          provide: FormBuilder,
          useValue: fb
        }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyTestedComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    eventEmitterSpy = spyOn(component.action, 'emit');
    component.payment = fakePayment;
    configService = TestBed.get(ConfigurationService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    eventEmitterSpy.calls.reset();
    dialogServiceStub.confirmContinuation.calls.reset();
    paymentServiceStub.rejectPayments.calls.reset();
    paymentServiceStub.releasePayments.calls.reset();

    if (configSpy != null && configSpy.configuration != null)
      configSpy.configuration.calls.reset();

  })
});
```

In a test file, I would like to do something like this (but getting `null`):

`fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#btn-release')`

Comment: could you provide the whole test (both setup in beforeEach with all you pass there and the test itself)?

Comment: sure, I've provided a code example ;)

Comment: and what is MyTestedComponent? how is it related to template in the question?

Comment: The given HTML code is MyTestedComponent's HTML template